# Testing if two primitive wrapper Numbers represent equal primitive numbers

Tags: java, numbers, wrapper, equality, primitive

I am searching for a reliable way to test if two primitive wrapper `Numbers` (e.g. `Integer`, `Float`, `Double` etc.) represent equal primitive numbers.

For example the following if statement involving two primitive numbers yields `true`:

```
int i = 100;
double d = 100d;
if (i == d) {
    System.out.println("equal");
}
```

But the following if statement is of course `false` since the `Number` instances are of different classes (`Integer` and `Double`):

```
int i = 100;
double d = 100d;
Number n1 = i;
Number n2 = d;
if (n1.equals(n2)) {
    System.out.println("equal");
}
```

Is there some relialble generic test to see, if two instances of `Number` (of which I know are primitive wrappers) are equal in the sense that their primitive values are equal? In the same context: is there some reliable generic  test to see how instances of `Number` compare to each other with the other conditional operators `!=` `>`, `<`, `>=` and `<=`?

For now I came to the following solution, but I'm not sure if this is really reliable:

```
int i = 100;
double d = 100d;
Number n1 = i;
Number n2 = d;
if (n1.doubleValue() == n2.doubleValue()) {
    System.out.println("equal");
}
```

Comment: I think that your way is good since you are accessing the primitive values and you are doing that by calling doubleValue which make sure that there is no lost data

Answer (score 1):

That's ugly.

If I was given that assignment, and if I could not find a library to do it for me (I don't know of any such library off the top of my head), then I would write some ugly code:

I would use reflection to get the types of the two Numbers, and then I would look up in a table to find which of them could be cast to the other's type.

Then do the cast,

Then compare.

---

Your solution, cast everything to double, will work for most cases, but it will not work for comparing `long` values that are larger than about 2^56.  The `double` data type does not have sufficient precision to represent all of the `long` values that are larger than that.

Comment: Thanks for the information about the problem with my conversion to double. I thought about your suggested approach too but did hope I could somehow avoid reflection and instanceof testing...